# Cannot login Gnome on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I met some weird problem today. I did some code compiling stuffs, then update software package of the Ubuntu 14.04.2 and reboot. I can not login the GUI any more. After I input my username and password, the GUI get locked. I googled and found that it is a common problem for a long time, but I tried quite a number of solutions, but none of them works for me. The following are those I tried

- remove or change ownership of `~/.Xauthority`
- reinstall unity
- fall back to older gnome version

I wonder if any one met the same problem before? Any related information or hit will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you log in at one of the CLI virtual terminals (Ctrl-Alt-F1 etc.)? Are the ownership and permissions on your home directory correct? Is the disk full?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes I can log in at CLI virtual terminals. I have tried change the ownership and permissions of the ~/.Xauthority even remove it. But it doesn work for me. I have a lot of space left.

Comment: The ownership of the whole directory is important, not just the .Xauthority file; when logged in to the CLI, what does `ls -ld $HOME` say?

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling gdm?

Comment: @Zacharee1: How do you know, OP uses GDM? The default display manager on Ubuntu is LightDM, which can initiate Gnome sessions just as well.

Comment: I figure that if he has GNOME, he most likely has its display manager.

Comment: to steeldriver: ls -ld $HOME gives me drwxr-xr-x 29 shuda shuda 4096 Apr 16 00:33 /home/shuda

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: As a last resort you may want to create a new user and chown the old home folder to the new username

Comment: Thank your for all helps. I ended up reinstall the ubuntu 14.04.